# Generating IPA with gradle libgdx project

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, ipa, robovm

I try to generate my IPA with $ gradlew ios:generateIPA from commandline but I receive this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ios:createIPA'.
> No @Marshaler found for parameter 3 of @Callback method<org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication: long $cb$beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler$(org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication,org.robov    m.objc.Selector,java.lang.Runnable)>
```

I have unpacked the lastest robovm release under Downloads, and I also updated robovm eclipse plugin. All to 0.0.11.

My build.gradle is configurated with roboVMVersion = "0.0.11".

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

It's necessary to create a new App ID from member center, if I want to generate a IPA of my game.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, any chance you could give a bit more information? I've generated an App Store and Ad Hoc App ID and downloaded the appropriate provisioning profile, and made sure that the App ID there matches the App ID for my robovm.properties app.id section. Any suggestions for something I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a fix but a workaround that helped me: instead of using ./gradlew ios:createIPA, install the RoboVM eclipse plugin, then right click the iOS project, RoboVM tools, and package for app store/distribution, then select the appropriate profiles. Works great for me.